# If f(z)=g(z)h(z) and g(z) is analytic at $a$ then does this imply that both h(z) and g(z) are analytic at $a$

Tags: complex-analysis

If f(z)=g(z)h(z) and g(z) is analytic at $a$ then does this imply that both h(z) and g(z) are analytic at $a$?

Or in other words, can the product of a analytic and non-analytic function be analytic at point $a$?. Obviously if the analytic function is 0, then the product is just the 0 function which is analytic, so we should assume that the analytic function is not the zero function.

Comment: Take $g=1$ and $f=h$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Suspect typo, that the OP (i.e. original poster) intends premise that $f(z)$ analytic, not $g(z)$ analytic.

Comment: For an example of two non-analytic functions whose product is analytic take $g(z)=\overline z, h(z)=\frac z {\overline z}$ for $z \neq 0$, $h(0)=0$.